# Firefox adding extra padding to css menu

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS menu which appears correctly in both IE 8 and Chrome. However in firefox
extra padding seems to be added and pushes the last menu item to the next row.

Can anyone have a look at the below and tell me how to fix it.

CSS BELOW:

```
#wrap {
    width: 920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#cssmenu{
    border:none;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font: 67.5% 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;   
    }
#cssmenu ul{
    background:#333333;
    height:37px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2580a2;
    }
#cssmenu li{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;

    }
#cssmenu li a{
    background:#333333 url('images/seperator.gif') bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#cccccc;
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:37px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 22px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    }



#cssmenu li a:hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover a{
    background: #2580a2;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#cssmenu li ul{
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:225px;
    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
    }
#cssmenu li:hover ul{
    display:block;

    }
#cssmenu li li {
    background:url('images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:225px;
    }
#cssmenu li:hover li a{
    background:none;

    }
#cssmenu li ul a{
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
    }
#cssmenu li ul a:hover, #cssmenu li ul li:hover a{
    background:#2580a2 url('images/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
    border:0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#cssmenu p{
    clear:left;
    }
```

HTML below:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="menu_assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='index.html'><span>HOME</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>OPERATIONS</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>AIRWORTHINESS</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>REGULATIONS AND POLICY</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>MANUALS AND FORMS</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>EDUCATION</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>ABOUT CASA</span></a></li>
   <li id='cssmenulast'><a href='#'><span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you setup a demo of your code on JSFiddle.net ? you can put your html and css in and save it as a link that you can paste here.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/EHcZb/

Comment: what vesion of **ff** you have?

Comment: Version 19.0.2 firefox

Comment: looks find in ff20 on windows 7

Comment: @sephiith now check to this demo http://jsfiddle.net/EHcZb/4/ and check to my answer ..........

Comment: I think, the main problem here is trying to get text displayed with the same width in all situations. That is not realistic, because font rendering differs in browsers and depend on parameters like zoom, device resolution etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now used to `display:inline-block;` and **remove** `float left` in your **li**

**as like this**

```
#cssmenu ul{
white-space:nowrap;  // add this line
font-size:0;   // add this line
}

#cssmenu li{
float:left; // remove this line
display:inline-block; // add this line
vertical-align:top; // add this line
font-size:10px;
padding:0px;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EHcZb/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `padding-start:0px`

```
#container {
 -moz-padding-start: 0px;    // firefox
 -webkit-padding-start: 0px; // safari
 padding-left: 0px;          // chrome
}
```

`padding-start` automatically applies to `<li>` element.

Mozilla docs for `padding-start`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-padding-start

More resource on webkit-padding (*also including webkit-margin not including FF*): http://www.css-101.org/articles/base-styles-sheet-for-webkit-based-browsers/index.php

Comment: I have added that change and it didn't do anything.

Comment: have you tried applying on `#container ul {}`. sorry couldnt test for you. cannot get visual what is happening from my computer. can you take a screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: table` for this. Has the advantage of 100% width and can be scaled down for smaller resolutions.

```
#cssmenu ul
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu li
{
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}

#cssmenu li a
{
    padding: 0; /* use something like "0 10px" for more homogenous widths */
}
```

Now you can regulate the items width by playing with `padding` of `#cssmenu li a`. For an example see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XzgZZ/2/).